# Another way of getting Positive look behind

Tags: regex, lookbehind

is there any alternative to the positive lookbehind? I ask because I created the following regex that I will use in a specific software:

```
(?<=function )[a-zA-Z]([A-Za-z]|[0-9])*
```

However, apparently this software does not accept this form as a valid regex. So I would need a regex that uniquely takes the word followed by "function". Could anyone let me know how this could be done or if this could actually be done? The only way to do this that I know of is the lookbehind.

Comment: With no assertions, in the forward direction, you cannot ignore consumed characters in the overall match unless you're using PCRE compatible engines that have the `\K` construct after the part not to be included. In your case that would be `function \K[a-zA-Z]([A-Za-z]|[0-9])*`. But it is doubtful assertions would not be allowed and `\K` is. https://regex101.com/r/r6rZCw/1 And if it absolutely has to be the match group overall, this is of course the only way without assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to find the string "function" followed by a function name with letters and digits?  No lookarounds are necessary.

```
function [a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Note that your original `[A-Za-z]|[0-9]` is better written as `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

EDIT: If you want just the word after "function" then you use a capture group:

```
function ([a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

How you use the capture group depends on the tool or language you're using, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Almost that, maybe I expressed myself badly. What I'm looking for is an expression that just registers the word after the function. The word "function" should not come with it.

Comment: just put parentheses around the second part : function ([a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*)  and what you want will be in group1